# Getting image name when user clicks image within the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, web-services, camera

I am currently working on a project where i am clicking an image using camera or let the user select it from the picture gallery and setting the image on uiimageview. I successfully get the image name when user selects it from picture gallery but unable to get image name when user clicks using camera within the app.how to implement it ? i have to send image with image name using web-services.

Comment: First you have to store image in document/cache directory or in photo library to get name of image.

Comment: create that name manually from your side... for webservice you tell save the image that I give with this name and not that use the image with this name...

Answer (score 0):

In your imagePicker delegate method:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
        UIImage *chosenImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        if (chosenImage == nil) {
            chosenImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        }    
    NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(chosenImage);
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *localFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myphoto.png"];
        [webData writeToFile:localFilePath atomically:YES];
        chosenImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:localFilePath];
    }
```

`localFilePath` will be your image name. Hope this helps you.